# Protect img for google

Tags: html, web, server

If I create a folder on the server with pictures, I would like to load them ONLY for users with the correct password.

in short:

the user enters the password and then we use Ajax to load the image as img src syntax into the HTML file.

I realize that the direct image call is also possible without a password. However, the pictures are in very unusual folder paths.

what I'm interested in:

if Google or any other search engine crawls / indexes my page, will these images also be inserted and could appear in Google Image Search?
 reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, search engines will only crawl your HTML page and links inside it, not the actual folder structure and files of your server. It actually shouldn't even have access to your server files :)

If your images are not linked in the page, you should be fine.

That said, you can always use a robots.txt. From the official documentation:

> A robots.txt file tells search engine crawlers which pages or files the crawler can or can't request from your site.
>
> Use robots.txt to manage crawl traffic, and also to prevent image, video, and audio files from appearing in Google search results.

Link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en

Comment: As your answer was 2 min earlier, I deleted mine. No need to double post same info twice. Cheers :-)